# VFP - Repositioning in a grid

Tags: navigation, visual-foxpro

A grid grdmain has a recordsource cDetail.  cDetail is a cursor with just 2 columns :

CREATE CURSOR cDetail (tProd C(16), tValue N(4))

A button on the form can reposition to a different row in the grid:

```
cmdPosition.Click()
     SELECT cDetail
     GOTO  <record>
     Thisform grdmain.setfocus()
```

. . . This works fine.

I would now like to be able to reposition on a row in the grid by entering a suitable value into Column2.text1 of the grid.

Have included similar code (not including Setfocus()) in the Column2.text1.valid() method, but the selected cell remains on the same row  -  I must be doing something wrong!

Thanks.  Andrew

Comment: I don't see the code where you are specifying the column and row that you want to actually getfocus() or setfocus() to.  The above code simply sets the focus to the grid itself.

Comment: Thanks, Hank.

It is true that the code only specifies the row of the grid which is to receive focus.

The GOTO <record> does this.

If you need to specify both the row and column in the grid, the sequence could be :

GOTO <record>
Thisform.grdmain.Column2.text1.setfocus()

What is happening is that this code will indeed set focus to the desired row (and column, if required) of the grid, when it is called from a command button.

But it is not effective, certainly for the row, when called from within the column2.text.valid() method.  And this is what I would like to achieve

Comment: Have you tried using the `Column2.Text1.LostFocus` event?

Comment: Thanks Supersnake.  Yes have tried putting the code in Column2.Text1.LostFocus().  But that does not reposition on a different row; I must be doing something wrong, if it works for you!

Do you have an example of code where altering a value in column2.text1 causes focus to a different row in the grid.  Would be most grateful

Answer (score 2):

To do what you're trying to do, you must first set focus AWAY from the grid. The row you're currently focused on interactively will always override any manual GOTO commands. You'll also need to put your code in the LostFocus event handler of the grid column's textbox (to avoid the "Cannot call SetFocus from within a When, Valid" error).

Assume this code is in "Column2.Text1.LostFocus". I have a button on the form named "command1" for this example. Further, I'm arbitrarily going to row 2.

```
thisform.command1.SetFocus()
GOTO  2
thisform.grdmain.SetFocus()
```

Comment: Steve beat me to the punch! For a touch more info: The VFP grid tries its best to keep the ActiveRow and RelativeRow intact during operations by contained controls. If you step through it you'll see that the `RECNO()` does in fact change, but returns to its previous value as soon as `Valid` completes. Note that the `LostFocus` above may not always trigger when you want. For example, navigating up and down `Column2` never causes `Column2.Text1` to lose focus.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  Your suggestion with button 'Command1' is almost identical to the code in the original question.  I am however looking for a solution which repositions in the grid when a value is entered in column2.text1, _not_ by having to press another button.  Is this possible?  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The code I posted above is for the LostFocus of the textbox within Column2. So no button press needed. You do need to replace the reference to "thisform.command1" with some button that actually exists on your form.

Comment: (Sorry for the delay)   Thank you Steve.

Yes, you are right.  I detect the need for a change in the row of the grid in Column2.Text1.valid().  If I then set a flag to tell Column2.text1.lostfocus() to execute the setfocus() commands, that does the trick.  Seems strange to be calling setfocus() but never actually getting to the destination, but it works !

As an alternative, you can execute the GOTO instruction in the afterrowcolchange() method.  That way you don’t need to issue the setfocus().